# More suitable method for finding an index of an instance with a certain value

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of instances of class `PlayerProp`. I want to find the index of an instance in that array with a specified value.

To explain `PlayerProp` contains an instance of another class `Player`. I need to find the index of the instance with that class `Player` and remove it from the index.

So far to attempt this problem I have just made a second Array containing the variable I need to identify the instance in the first array. 
I think this should work, the second array index should have the same index as the first array.

I think this should work but I feel like this isn't a very sure-fire way of doing it. Is there a more reliable way to do this?

```
List<String> playerListCrazyMode = new ArrayList<String>();
List<PlayerProp> playerCrazyMode = new ArrayList<PlayerProp>();

private void enableCrazy() {

    for(Player player: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        playerListCrazyMode.add(player.getName());
        playerCrazyMode.add(new PlayerProp(player));
    }


}
private void disableCrazy() {
    playerListCrazyMode.clear();
    playerCrazyMode.clear();
}

@EventHandler
public void join(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player playerJoin = e.getPlayer();
    playerListCrazyMode.add(playerJoin.getName());
    playerCrazyMode.add(new PlayerProp(playerJoin));
}

@EventHandler
public void leave(PlayerQuitEvent e) {
    Player playerLeave = e.getPlayer();
    int indexPlayer = playerListCrazyMode.indexOf(playerLeave.getName());
    playerCrazyMode.remove(indexPlayer);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little mistake in the logic of leave method.

1. When removing Player from List "playerCrazyMode", should also remove from 
   "playerListCrazyMode" as well.
2. Are you expecting duplicate names? if yes then this solution will not work.
3. Searching and deleting from middle in list is expensive. Do you have to use Arraylist

only?

Comment: The reason I used a list was because on initiation I need to create instances of all the players when a method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what `indexOf` does internally is traversing the array element-by-element anyway. Therefore, the general idea of the algorithm is as follows:

```
public static <T> int firstIndexOf(Predicate<T> test, List<T> list) {
    int idx = -1;
    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (test.test(list.get(i)) {
                idx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return idx;
}
```

In your case, the `Predicate` would be `player -> name.equals(player.getName())`